# Limiting memory for Sybase SQL Anywhere

Tags: sybase, sybase-sql-anywhere

I have to use Sybase's SQL Anywhere for a project so it has been put on a VM. Memory consumption is particularly high for a not overly taxed database and it's putting a lot of pressure on the VM.

The process is dbsrv12.exe and it's consuming >3GB of memory. Is there a way I can limit that to something more sensible and suitable for a VM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sybase's SQL Anywhere has startup parameters to control the min/max cache settings.

```
  -c  for the initial cache memory setting
  -ch for the maximum cache memory setting
  -ci for the minimum cache memory setting
```

If you set these appropriately it should constain the memory usage from the cache.

Here is a SQL Anywhere 12.0 page with those settings:
http://dcx.sybase.com/1200/en/dbusage/limiting-using-perform.html

Comment: Thanks for your help this is installed as a service so I used the sc config command to change it as follows: sc config SQLANYs binPath= "C:\Program Files\SQL Anywhere 12\Bin64\dbsrv12.exe -ch 1g -c 256m" but on restart Process Explorer still shows the process with a Private Bytes consumption of >3GB

Comment: @noonand Are you using AWE cache? Are you running x64 version of SQL Anywhere?

Comment: Path for the executable is C:\Program Files\SQL Anywhere 12\Bin64\dbsrv12.exe so I presume it is the x64 version. The OS is 2008 R2 x64. Isn't AWE a nasty software hack to let x86 address more than 4GB along with nasty hardware hacks like 36-bit PAE extensions in the CPU? Surely that has no place in a (albeit virtual) x64 OS/CPU?

Comment: Awarding answer on this as it prodded me to go look at Sybase central. There I could configure this (and a world of other options)